# How to get statistics for structural parameters after estimating a reduced form model

Tags: structural-estimation

Let say I have some structural model $y_t = \alpha + (1+\psi)x_t$. I estimate the model $y_t = \alpha + \beta x_t + e_t$ using OLS. I can back out the structural parameter $\psi$ by hand.

How about standard errors and t-statistics for $\psi$? Can some econometric software do that? Or do I need to do that by hand? By hand I mean use the model $(y_t-x_t) = \alpha_1 + \psi_1 x_t + u_t$ to get standard errors for $\psi$?

Update: I checked in stata, SE for $\psi_1$ and $\beta$ are the same. So I guess that is it. Thus, standard errors for reduced-form and structural parameters are the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends$\ldots$
In your setting, the structural parameter $\psi$ is simply $1$ minus the value of the reduced form parameter $\beta$:
$$
\psi = 1 - \beta.
$$
In such case, the mean of the estimator $\psi_n$ will be simply the mean of $1 - \beta_n$ and they will have the same variance (as the variance does not change if we add a fixed number or change sign).

If we have a general (non-linear) transformation:
$$
\psi = g(\beta),
$$
then the most common way to proceed (and to get asymptotic consistent standard errors) is  by using the delta-method, which is based on a first order Taylor expansion ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)). In particular, if $g$ is $C^1$ and if:
$$
\sqrt{n}(\beta_n - \beta) \to^D {\cal N}(0, \sigma^2),
$$
we will have that:
$$
\sqrt{n}(g(\beta_n) - g(\beta)) = \sqrt{n}(\psi_n - \psi) \to^D {\cal N}(0, \sigma^2 \cdot [g'(\beta)]^2).
$$
So the asymptotic mean of $\sqrt{n}(\psi_n - \psi)$ will be equal to zero (which means that $\psi_n$ is consistent and the asymptotic variance is the asymptotic variance of $\beta_n$ multiplied by the derivative $g'(\beta)$ squared.

Notice that if $g$ is a simple translation then $g' = \pm 1$ so the square is $1$ and the variance will be equal to $\sigma^2$.

To estimate $\sigma^2 \cdot [g'(\beta)]^2$ you can use the consistent plugin estimator:
$$
\hat \sigma^2_n \cdot [g'(\beta_n)]^2. 
$$
where $\hat \sigma^2_n$ is a consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that in MATLAB. Lemme ask though if you've tried this in other econometric software - STATA, EVIEWS, OXMETRICS, R, PYTHON?